# PHP read every 3rd line from file and save it to another file

Tags: php

I want to read every 3rd line from file1 and save it as a new file2.

This is what I am trying, but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
$myfile = file("file1.txt");
$lines = file($myFile);
$newFileContent= $lines[2];
file_put_contents("file2.txt", $newFileContent);
```

So, if file1.txt has the following content:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

The file2.txt should contain only:

```
3
6
```

Comment: Look in to the modulo operator. That will solve your problem.

Comment: I did but not sure I see how it applies.

Comment: Why are you calling `file` twice, once over the actual file and once over the array returned by the first `file`?

Comment: yeah sorry, that's a mistake, typed it in on the first line by mistake

Comment: Show me what you did with modulo.

Comment: I read through it here, it just doesn't make any sense to what I am trying to do and that is to get out every 3rd line: http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php

Comment: @Difster Modulo isn't the correct tool for the job here, is it? The idea would be to iterate over the array with a step of 3 instead of 1; surely you could just accomplish that with a simple `for` loop?

Comment: every loop I've tried didn't work... but thanks for trying to help out

Comment: @btyewave - I suppose that would work also.

Comment: hint `if ($arrayKey % 3) {`

Comment: I agree modulo would be the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *actual* easiest way would be to use a normal `for` loop. The array is non-associative, so it makes no sense to use an expensive `foreach` over the entire array.

To exactly replicate your sample data, just use something like the following:

```
$lines = file('file1.txt');

$newContent = '';

$len = count($lines); // saves us from calling count() on every iteration

for ($i = 2; $i < $len; $i += 3) {
    $newContent .= $lines[$i];
}

file_put_contents('file2.txt', $newContent);
```

[Working demo](https://ideone.com/ug3SUN)

Comment: `foreach()` is faster then `for()`, how is it expensive?

Comment: Because you're iterating over every element instead of just every 3rd one?